# Can't figure out error with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextarea

The following is my program. the goal is to convert from a roman numeral to an Arabic number after a user types in the numeral and presses the enter key.

This is a homework assignment and we are forced to user `JTextAreas` in lieu of `JTextFields`.

My error exists on the line: `enterRomanNumber.addActionListener(handler)`;
The error reads:

> "The method addActionListener(ArabicToRomanGUI.HandlerForTextArea) is
>   undefined for the type JTextArea"

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error or how to correct it, can someone please advise.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
public class ArabicToRomanGUI extends JFrame
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextArea enterRomanNumber = new JTextArea();
JLabel label = new JLabel();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();


//TestArea contructor adds jtextArea to jframe
public ArabicToRomanGUI()
{
    super("Convert a Roman Numeral");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //Text field to enter a roman numeral
    enterRomanNumber = new JTextArea(1,25);
    enterRomanNumber.setText("Delete this text and Enter a Roman Numerial Here!");
    //enterRomanNumber.setAlignmentX(0);
    //enterRomanNumber.setAlignmentY(0);

    add(enterRomanNumber);

    HandlerForTextArea handler = new HandlerForTextArea();
    enterRomanNumber.addActionListener(handler);
}

private class HandlerForTextArea implements ActionListener
{
    //used to process textArea events
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String userInput = "";
        userInput = enterRomanNumber.getText();
        userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();

        ConversionLogic.ConvertFromRomanToArabic(userInput); //converts user string of Roman numerals to an int in arabic
        String arabicNumberAsString = ConversionLogic.getConvertedRomanNumeral();
        enterRomanNumber.setText(arabicNumberAsString);

        //user pressed enter in JTextField enterNumberField
        if(e.getSource() == enterRomanNumber)
        {
            //enterRomanNumber.setText(arabicNumberAsString);
            if (ConversionLogic.getCheckFail() == true)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The Roman Numeral entered is Invalid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The arabic equivalent is " + arabicNumberAsString + "." , "Conversion Successful", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

    }
}
}//end inner class TextAreaHandler
```

Comment: Where would this method come from? [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) neither defines or inherits such method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***For a better answer, see*** @MadProgrammer ***'s answer.***

**My solution:**

There is no ActionListener for JTextArea.

So just use `KeyListener` instead

```
HandlerForTextArea handler = new HandlerForTextArea();
enterRomanNumber.addKeyListener(handler);
```

Implements KeyListener

```
private class HandlerForTextArea implements KeyListener
{

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg0.getKeyCode() == VK_ENTER){
            // TODO Your bussiness
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: I have deleted my actionListener and switched to Keylistener. I took my same logic and placed it within keyReleased as instructed, however I keep getting an error on the line that looks for the ENTER key to be released tell me  "VK_ENTER cannot be resolved to a variable" Do you know why this is?

Comment: I resolved my issue. I was putting == VK_ENTER and forgetting to place KeyEvent.VK_ENTER.

Comment: Haha. actually I dont know KeyEvent.VK_ENTER . The symbol VK_ENTER based on system I usually use in C#.

Comment: No, No, NO, don't use `KeyListener` on text components!  If you "really" wanted to know when [Enter] was pressed, then you should be overriding the component's `VK_ENTER` key binding.  The OP has already been warned off using `KeyListener`s in a previous question and know you're dragging them back kicking and screaming!  `KeyListener`s are simply a poor choice for ANY text component

Answer (score 2):

`KeyListener`s are NEVER appropriate solutions to use with text components, if you want to be notified when a text component changes, you use a `DocumentListener`, if you want to change/filter what can be entered into a text component, you use a `DocumentFilter`, if you need to change a special key, like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you should use a key binding

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

One of the problems you could have with `KeyListener` is not knowing when the key stroke is processed by the text component, in your case, it may not be a major issue, but it could change the way the program works on different platforms.

Instead, you can override the `JTextArea`'s key binding for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (named `insert-break`).  This provides you with the ability to actually change the behavior of the key stroke, or, in your case, manage how you process the event.  For example, this replaces the `Action` for the text area's <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, but retains the previous/default behavior...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class KeyBindingsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KeyBindingsTest();
    }

    public KeyBindingsTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;

        public TestPane() {
            ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            ActionMap am = ta.getActionMap();

            Action proxy = am.get("insert-break");
            am.put("insert-break", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // You can process the event through the original action BEFORE
                    // you do your own processing
                    //proxy.actionPerformed(e);
                    System.out.println("You pressed the enter key, you can have candy");
                    // Or you can process the event through the original action AFTER
                    // you do your own processing, you have now gained control
                    proxy.actionPerformed(e);
                }
            });

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(ta);
        }

    }

}
```

Now, you could even go to the extent for creating your own `JTextArea` which supported `ActionPerformed`...

```
public class ActionableTextArea extends JTextArea {

    private String actionCommand;

    public ActionableTextArea() {
        installKeyBindings();
    }

    public ActionableTextArea(String text) {
        super(text);
        installKeyBindings();
    }

    public ActionableTextArea(int rows, int columns) {
        super(rows, columns);
        installKeyBindings();
    }

    public ActionableTextArea(String text, int rows, int columns) {
        super(text, rows, columns);
        installKeyBindings();
    }

    public ActionableTextArea(Document doc) {
        super(doc);
        installKeyBindings();
    }

    public ActionableTextArea(Document doc, String text, int rows, int columns) {
        super(doc, text, rows, columns);
        installKeyBindings();
    }

    protected void installKeyBindings() {
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();
        Action proxy = am.get("insert-break");
        am.put("insert-break", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // You can process the event through the original action BEFORE
                // you do your own processing
                //proxy.actionPerformed(e);
                fireActionPerformed();
                    // Or you can process the event through the original action AFTER
                // you do your own processing, you have now gained control
                proxy.actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void setActionCommand(String actionCommand) {
        this.actionCommand = actionCommand;
    }

    public String getActionCommand() {
        return actionCommand;
    }

    protected void fireActionPerformed() {
        ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
        if (listeners.length > 0) {
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, getActionCommand());
            for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }
    }

}
```