# addactionListener(this) How do I place this line of code in correctly?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextarea

So I am designing a chatroom and before I can read up on sockets I need to finish up this GUI. Basically I am mostly using [TextDemo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java) as my guide. I like how it displays so I figured it'd be an easy spot to start with my code. In my code it breaks whenever I try to put in:

```
input.addActionListener(this);
```

When I comment out that line it goes back to displaying/running perfectly. Due to my errors, it looks like I'm putting it in the wrong location. I've tried moving it around a bit but I don't seem to have the problem solving skills to fix this yet. Can someone help correct me and explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{     
   private final static String newline = "\n";

///// CREATING THE GUI /////
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chatroom");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JPanel chatpanel = new JPanel();
JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
JPanel sendpanel = new JPanel();
JTextArea chat = new JTextArea(19, 49);
JTextArea input = new JTextArea(3, 40);

JScrollPane chatscroll = new JScrollPane(chat,
                                         JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                         JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
JScrollPane inputscroll = new JScrollPane(input,
                                         JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                         JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

JButton connectbutton = new JButton("Connect");
JButton disconnectbutton = new JButton("Disconnect");
JButton send = new JButton("Send");
JLabel label = new JLabel();

///// GUI CONSTRUCTOR /////
public GUI()
{
   chatroomGUI();
}

public void chatroomGUI()
{      
   ///// GUI DISPLAY /////
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setSize(800, 450);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
   panel2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
   chatpanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
   inputpanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
   sendpanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

   ///// ACTION LISTENER /////
   //input.addActionListener(this);

   chat.setEditable(false);
   chat.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
   chat.setLineWrap(true);
   chat.setWrapStyleWord(true);

   input.setFont(new Font("Fialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
   input.setLineWrap(true);
   input.setWrapStyleWord(true);

   sendpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
   sendpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 50));
   chatpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   chatpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(565, 320));

   ///// ADD AREA /////
   chatpanel.add(chatscroll);
   inputpanel.add(inputscroll);
   inputpanel.add(sendpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
   sendpanel.add(send, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   panel.add(connectbutton);
   panel.add(disconnectbutton);
   panel.add(label);

   panel2.add(chatpanel);
   panel2.add(inputpanel);

   frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
   frame.add(panel2);
}

///// ACTION PERFORMED /////
/*The following will take any text that is typed inside of
the "input" area and display it in the "chat" screen area.*/ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
   String text = input.getText();
   chat.append(text + newline);
   input.selectAll();
   chat.setCaretPosition(chat.getDocument().getLength());
}
}
```

Note: My main is in another class. That code just simply looks like:

```
public class Chatroom
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
   javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
         public void run()
         {
            new GUI();
         }
     });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JTextArea` does not support the `ActionListener` API, so it does not have a `addActionListener` method.  You should consult the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) and [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) first

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might consider using a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) or a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) or use the key bindings API, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071844/cant-figure-out-error-with-actionlistener/33091886#33091886)

Comment: Oh that must be right! I didn't think the JTextField would be so different than the JTextArea. Thanks so much! I'll work on finding a way around that.

Comment: Have a look at the last linked example, which demonstrates a custom `JTextArea` with `ActionListener` support