# Java in NetBeans - Adding actionEvents with custom parameters

Tags: java, netbeans, customization, actionlistener

I'm working on something in NetBeans, and I want to create an actionListener in a jTextPane for when the user presses Enter. However, I also need to input a String array (from a different subroutine within the source code) into the listener. But in NetBeans, events are generated automatically and I'm not allowed to edit this apparently extremely sensitive code. So, then, I tried typing up my own event thing (sorry about my terminology; I'm very new to GUI programming):

```
private void jTextPaneEnterPressed(KeyEvent evt, String[] stringArray)
    {
        int key = evt.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            // do something when the user presses enter that involves the program knowing what stringArray is
        }
    }
```

But when I run the program, pressing Enter in the text pane does nothing. I understand that this is because there is no actionListener associated with `jTextPaneEnterPressed`, but NetBeans gives no option for such customized code.
So what I want to know is either how I can pass in my own parameters when NetBeans creates an event handler, *or* how I can write my own actionListener alongside this actionPerformed block.

(And for the record, this is not an import problem)

I have tried looking this up, but have found nothing specific, as all other similar issues are not relevant to NB. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT: This may seem like a trivial problem to most, but I'm open to any actual answers that tell me how to get done what I am trying to do, though I would prefer to stick with NetBeans. All I need is for the action listener to know that this string array exists, because the program needs to deal with that array when the user presses Enter. I'm sorry I can't give any specific context, but it's too much to get into.

Comment: Forget about NetBeans.  It's just an IDE.  Java is what matters.  You should take a closer look at the API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Comment: The basic answer is two fold, first, you can't, it simply makes no sense. Second, you should be using key bindings instead of KeyListener. Once the event has been triggered, you need to gather the I formation you need, there is a prescribed contract that needs to be upheld in order for these things to work

Comment: @MadProgrammer Come again? Like I said, I'm new to this. Could you explain what key bindings are?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343355/java-linux-terminal-in-jpanel/32343778#32343778) shows how you can listen to the [Enter] key for a `JTextArea`, [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071844/cant-figure-out-error-with-actionlistener/33091886#33091886) adds `ActionListener` support for  a `JTextArea`